How to effectively substring UTF-8 encoded String to a certain amount of used bytes?
I am looking for a solution to the problem I have faced recently in Java: to limit the filename to 255 bytes in UTF-8.
Given that a single UTF-8 character can be represented by multiple bytes, this is not as simple as:
String sampleString = "컴퓨터";
byte[] bytes = sampleString.getBytes("utf8");
String limitedString = new String(bytes, 0, 5, "utf8");

because we can "cut" the character so that it will end up like in the case above:
컴�

I was looking for a good solution but I cannot find any. ChatGPT suggested using StringBuilder, and adding a character one-by-one and checking if this reached the limit, something like this (this isn't ChatGPT's code, my own interpretation):
String sampleString = "컴퓨터";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < sampleString.length(); i++) {
    String temp = sb.toString() + sampleString.codePointAt(i); // build temporary string
    if (temp.getBytes("utf8").length > 5) {                    // convert it back to bytes and check size
        break;                                                 // if it does not fit, break
    }
    sb.append(sampleString.codePointAt(i));                    // add that tested character otherwise
}

and then the result is as expected:
컴

but I see this as a very memory-expensive solution. Perhaps a much more performant one exists out there?

You shouldn't be using charAt (which may split unicode characters), you should be using codePointAt (which doesn't).

Thank you @AndyTurner, good point. Indeed, charAt returns char which does not fit all UTF-8 characters.

you probably meant that char does not fit (most) UNICODE characters

afaik Windows uses UTF-16 to encode file names, so that would be a limit of 255/2 characters if you're using that OS

This is in Linux context

@user85421, yes, my mistake - I meant a single UTF-8 character can oversize char

Oh I see. OK then maybe: public static String truncateToMaxBytes(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, CharacterCodingException {String result = null;int[] oneCodepoint = new int[1];ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_BYTES);for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {oneCodepoint[0] = s.codePointAt(i);byte[] a = new String(oneCodepoint, 0, 1).getBytes("UTF-8");if (bb.position() + a.length <= bb.limit()) {bb.put(a);}}CharsetDecoder csd = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();result = csd.decode(bb.rewind()).toString();return result;}

What does “to max length” mean?

@user3840170, yes, this may be misleading, I will change the title

Use the fact that in UTF-8, every byte of a multi-byte code point, except the first byte, starts with binary digits 10xxxxxx. If you are looking at such a byte, you know that it's part of a multi-byte code point and you need to scan backwards until you find a byte starting 11xxxxxx to find the start of that code point. Therefore, you can chop your byte array at the required limit and then remove any incomplete code point at the end, if there is one:
    String sampleString = "컴퓨터";
    byte[] bytes = sampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int limit = 5;
    String limitedString;
    if (limit >= bytes.length) {
        limitedString = sampleString;
    } else {
        while (limit > 0 && (bytes[limit] & 0xC0) == 0x80)
            limit--;
        limitedString = new String(bytes, 0, limit, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }


@RemyLebeau no, note that I am starting at the limit, not at the end of the string. Therefore there can only be one incomplete code point to remove. I've modified the explanation in my answer to make that more obvious.

@RemyLebeau the limit variable is not an index, but a length. Therefore, what I'm looking at with bytes[limit] is the byte after the last byte of the string. When that byte is a part of a UTF-8 sequence (10xxxxxx), it means that the previous byte also belongs to that character. If bytes[limit] is either 0xxxxxxx or 11xxxxxx, it means that the byte after the string bytes[0 to limit-1] is the start of a new code point, and therefore the string bytes[0 to limit-1] is complete and intact.

@RemyLebeau here is a unit test that proves this works as intended. (It's a unit test in main with manual assertions because the online compiler doesn't support JUnit or the assert statement.)

UTF-8 is designed such that the 1st byte of an encoded codepoint specifies the number of bytes it actually takes up.  So you can simply sum up the codepoint byte counts until you reach your desired max byte count, eg:
int getUtf8SeqLen(byte b) {
    if ((b & 0x80) == 0x00) return 1; // 0xxxxxxx
    if ((b & 0xE0) == 0xC0) return 2; // 110xxxxx
    if ((b & 0xF0) == 0xE0) return 3; // 1110xxxx
    if ((b & 0xF8) == 0xF0) return 4; // 11110xxx
    throw new Exception("Invalid");
}

String sampleString = ...; // "컴퓨터"
byte[] bytes = sampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int maxBytes = ...; // 255
String limitedString;
if (bytes.length <= maxBytes) {
    limitedString = sampleString;
} else {
    int numBytes = 0, newLength = 0;
    do {
        int seqLen = getUtf8SeqLen(bytes[newLength]);
        numBytes += seqLen;
        if (numBytes > maxBytes) break;
        newLength = numBytes;
    }
    while (newLength < bytes.length);
    limitedString = new String(bytes, 0, newLength, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

Alternatively, since you are converting the bytes back to a String, you could simply avoid the byte[] array altogether and iterate the original String as-is, summing up encoded codepoint byte counts, eg:
int getUtf8SeqLen(int cp) {
    if (cp <= 0x007F)   return 1; // 0xxxxxxx
    if (cp <= 0x07FF)   return 2; // 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    if (cp <= 0xFFFF)   return 3; // 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    if (cp <= 0x10FFFF) return 4; // 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    throw new Exception("Invalid");
}

String sampleString = ...; // "컴퓨터"
int maxBytes = ...; // 255
int numBytes = 0, newLength = 0;
while (newLength < sampleString.length()) {
    int cp = sampleString.codePointAt(newLength);
    numBytes += getUtf8SeqLen(cp);
    if (numBytes > maxBytes) break;
    newLength += Character.charCount(cp);
}
String limitedString = sampleString.substring(0, newLength);


I like the second way you did it, as it's more direct not having to create a byte array.
